# Publish on facebook without auth (with user interaction)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

I'm trying to do something that doesn't seem to hard, but I just can't find how to achieve it. I have a web app with a leaderboard, and I would like to give the user the opportunity to share his score on facebook. There would be a link "publish to facebook" that would either bring up a popup, either redirect to a page on facebook, in both cases with a dialog to publish a story on his wall.

This has to be easy and very direct, the user should not be prompted for allowing an app or anything like that. However, it's been quite a while since I've done any app do that : is it still possible ?

FYI this is a ruby on rails 3.2 app

Thanks for you time guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is to include the [facebook javascript sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) in your app page and then just call the [FB.ui](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) method for opening a [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).

You can also open up a popup of your own and direct it to the direct url of the same feed dialog:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=APP_ID&
  link=LINK_URL&
  picture=PICTURE_URL&
  name=NAME&
  caption=CAPTION&
  description=DESCRIPTION&
  message=MESSAGE_AS_THE_USER&
  redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL
```

It's all there in the feed dialog page.

Comment: Looks like they deprecated "message".. Kind of useless for me then. But thanks!

Comment: The _message_ field was removed because apps misused it. What you can do is use the [open graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) to have a ruby view that just outputs the og tags, with that you can create what ever you want and then when popping the fb feed dialog just post that link, facebook will extract all the info from the og tags, and the user is left to write his own messsage.

Comment: Yep I've just seen that. It might do the job. Thanks again :)